# Unable to get all variables defined

Tags: python, file, text-files

```
class exersise:

    def run(self):
        print('Running works')
    def jump(self):
        print('Jump works')
    def swim(self):
        print('Swim works')

    commands_table = {'Run':run, 'Jump':jump, 'Swim':swim}

with open('commands.txt', 'r') as command_file:
    for cmd in command_file:
        cmd = cmd.strip()
        commands_table[cmd]()
```

im not sure why commands_table is undefined, when i move the commands_table into the "with open" statement the commands "run","jump" and "swim" are now undefined. When I move the "with open" statement one indentation block across "cmd" and "command_file" then becomes undefined. I feel like im so close to getting it to work just cant find the right solution.

Comment: its part of the exercise class, so `exersisse.commands_table` would help you a little but still wont be usable since you're mapping instance methods in it

Comment: that actually gets rid of the definition issue, thanks!, but then yes another one crops up because im mapping methods, its now missing a self positional argument, hm, ill spend some time on this

Comment: @Pobl--you need to pass an exercise instance such as `exersise.commands_table[cmd](exersise())`

Comment: omg that did it, thankyou stranger!

Comment: @Pobi--glad to help.  Better overall to set an instance before the loop i.e. ` e = exersise()`.  Then you can use it for both the class reference and instance variable i.e. `e.commands_table[cmd](e)`

Answer (score 1):

Apply below modification for class methods and class variables.

```
obj = exersise
with open('commands.txt', 'r') as command_file:
    for cmd in command_file:
        cmd = cmd.strip()
        obj.commands_table[cmd](obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

Good try but you know how local variable should be called.
if so then use `exersise.command_table[cmd]()`
instead of

```
command_table[cmd]()
```

Comment: self positional argument is required hence your are calling class-method without using  class object.